# Visa of Central American countries for Bangladeshi Citizen having a valid US B1/B2 Visa

Tags: bangladeshi-citizens, central-america

I am a Bangladeshi citizen holding a valid US B1/B2 visa. I would like to plan a trip to the central American countries.

1. Panama
2. Costa Rica
3. Nicaragua
4. Hondurus
5. El Salvador
6. Guatemala
7. Belize

Can I travel to each of them with a valid US B1/B2 visa?

According to Wikipedia Honduras, El Salvador, and Guatemala won't allow and Belize will ask for $600 "repatriation fee". However, I could not find any official reference for any of them.

Could someone point  me to the right direction?

Comment: When are you planning to travel, where from, and when does your US visa expire? Have you used it at least once to enter the US? Some countries eg Panama seem to allow entry to B1/B2 holders but with conditions https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/

Comment: 1. I am planning to travel during September, 2021. 2. From either Istanbul or other central American country. 3. My US visa expires in February, 2022 and Canadian visa expires during October, 2021. 4. I haven't used it yet, however, before visiting to Central American countries, I will visit USA.